# android retrofit decrypt response parameters

Tags: android, json, retrofit, pojo

In my android application, I am using retrofit to call web services.

Here, from the server, I might get data in an encrypted format.

So, I have written method to decrypt data if it is encrypted.

I have a large number of POJO objects to handle different responses.

How can I call this method for each and every response?

Can I create Intercepters for it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can add a interceptor and intercept your response and do the decrypting. check interceptors in the retrofit doc

Comment: How is the data encrypted? The whole response or just some fields?

Comment: @Henry
Just some fields

Comment: @Raghunandan
But using intercepters, how could I reinitialize response pojo using decripted data ?

Comment: You could use setters on the POJOs that do the decryption.

Comment: don't you get the raw response in interceptor.

Comment: @Henry
The code is already developed.
And there is the huge number of classes where they had not created getters and setters.
Direct value

Comment: @Raghunandan
but from there how could I return the response pojo ?